# SSRS - Passing multiple values to a filter in sub report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've been stuck on a piece of work for some time and I haven't been able to find a solution and would like some support. I've scrubbed some of the data for anonymity.

I have a report that details actions taken by members of a team. Each action is a row in the original dataset.

[First page of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdSwm.png)

First I have two totals that are drillthroughs to a sub report displaying all rows of data.

Below this is a tablix that outlines each department, team and team member and the number of actions taken respectively.

Values highlighted in yellow indicate drill throughs to the sub report and are intended to only return whatever team/individual has been filtered.

I'm just not able to effectively pass the intended values through to the sub report.

At the moment I am able to return data correctly for individual people but the drill through does not work on a team, department and full total level.

In the drill through action to the sub report I have the following:

- pStartDate (@pStartDate)
- pEndDate (@pEndDate)
- pDispatchPerson [DispatchPerson] - Field in the original dataset

And then there is a parameter in the sub report called pDispatchPerson which is set to 'Hidden' and 'Allow Multiple Values'.

When I do try to drill through on a team or department level it seems to just pass through the first value it finds for Dispatch Person when I actually want it to pass through any included in that team or department.

Here are some things I have tried:

- Creating a parameter for Dispatch Person in the main report and setting the Default value to [DispatchPerson] in the dataset.
  Then setting the action parameter to pDispatchPerson [@pDispatchPerson] and setting a filter on the sub report to [DispatchPerson] IN [@pDispatchPerson]. This returns no data.
- Using SPLIT and JOIN in both the action on the drill through button and a filter on the sub report. This tends to throw an error because it doesn't seem to know what value to assign to pDispatchPerson.

I've tried a combination of the above in various instances and still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jordan

Answer (score 0):

I would change your subreport to accept two parameters, one for the person and one for the team.

In the dataset query for your subreport, the WHERE clause would contain logic to choose the correct records. e.g.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myTable a 
    WHERE (
           (a.TeamID = @TeamID AND @PersonID IS NULL)
           OR
           (a.PersonID = @PersonID AND @TeamID IS NULL)
          )
```

In you main report, just pass in the appropriate parameter value (either team or person id) and set the other value to null.